# PHP compare by percent

Tags: php

I'm seeking to make a program that can take different numbers from the database and compare them in a percent with the total of other database records.

```
Example: Database Numbers 1:100
         User: 65
```

```
Output: Your number is bigger than 35 percent of the Users
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps have a look to this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so the question can become more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute 2 database queries:

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` - will get total count of the users (let's say you store result in `$total` variable)
2. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE number < 65` - will count users that have the number fields less than 65 (let's name this `$selection` variable)

After that, it's simple math:

```php
$percent = $selection / $total * 100;

echo "Your Numbers is bigger than {$percent} percent of the Users";
```